# How to find exactly why patch failed?

Tags: diff, patch, unified-diff

I have a unified diff patch which patch rejects. A visual inspection of the diff file and the original code finds the code contains all text expected by the diff file in the correct location. I have tried --ignore-whitespace and -F3 for good measure but patch still fails. Does an option exist to report exactly what is causing the patch to fail?